how to send an email with attachment from google drive
I was wondering if there is a solution that I can look into
I currently have a Google form that requires users to input some information and upload an attachment
The submission is being reflected to Google sheet where it will be pulled to an Excel file via power query.
This Excel file will then be filled by a department on additional information (i.e recipient)
Is there a way for me to mass send email based on the recipient indicated and to attach the uploaded pdf (which comes in the form of a Google Drive link) as an attachment
Simple example of the Excel file (Columns)
Name: Jason
Content: Customer is asking...
Recipient: XXXXX@servicecenter.com
Attachment: https://drive.google.com/file/z/xx              |
I am stuck at the attachment portion as I can't think of any way to make the Google Drive link into its original upload pdf to be attached

I don't think you can attach the file just by having the link to it. But if I was you I would try to download it from the link and then attach it to the email and maybe delete the file after sending the email.
I am going to assume you are going to send the emails from Excel and that you already know how to do it using VBA. The first thing you have to make sure is that the file in the google drive is downloadable, maybe you can use Google Apps Script to share the file or something. You seem to have the links to the files already so maybe that is also covered.
Now from the file link you can extract the file id, and with the file id you can create a download link. Using this as an example I made this macro to test if I could download a pdf file from google drive and it worked.
Option Explicit

' Declare the URLDownloadToFileA function from urlmon.dll
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "urlmon" _
    (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
     ByVal szURL As String, _
     ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
     ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long

' Function to download a file from a URL
Private Function DownloadUrlFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Long
    RetVal = URLDownloadToFileA(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If RetVal = 0 Then DownloadUrlFile = True
End Function

' Sub where you would use the function
Sub DownloadFileFromURL()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim LocalFilename As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim googleFileId As String
    
    fileName = "fileName"
    gooogleFileId = "1IHw3AMI...2OW0f0"
    
    URL = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" & googleFileId & "&export=download"
    LocalFilename = "C:\Users\userName\Downloads\" & fileName & ".pdf"
    
    If DownloadUrlFile(URL, LocalFilename) Then
        Debug.Print "Download successful!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Download failed."
    End If
End Sub

With the file downloaded in your computer you should be able to attach it to the email using the local path.
